# Decode hexadecimals gas and gas price values "0xd9c5"

Tags: gas, gas-price, abi, hex

Hello i have following kvp:

```
{
  gas: "0xd9c5"
}
```

But the ABI do not have gas func and the interface is not able to decode it, any idea how to decode the gas to extract the value when is missing from the ABI/Interface

Comment: Sorry, what is kvp and where are you planning to use this? Maybe share a bit more code?

Answer (score 0):

**This gas value is an hexadecimal number.**

You can manually convert hex numbers to decimals online ([here](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html) is an example).

I don't know what framework you use, but this can also be done easily within your app. For instance, in javascript you could do `parseInt("0xd9c5")`.